# according to the punctuation，split the data in v2

Tags: r

I have one sheet named `match`. It includes two columns: `v1` and `v2`.

```
v1  v2
1   001;002
2   003,004;001
3   003;002,001
```

I want to divide the data in `v2` into several data without any punctuation. The result is as `match_new`：

```
V1  V2  V3  V4
1   001 002 
2   003 004 001
3   003 002 001
```

What you should notice is: the data in `match` `v2` have `";"` and `","`
this question is mainly divding the data according to punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `substr` function. I think it will be useful on a row-by-row basis. Alternatively change the txt file itself to a common punctuation, say semi-colon, and read the file in as a semi-colon delimited file.

Comment: can you give me the code? I want to learn the proccessing.